# Reactjs: Loading view based on response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

Looking for a way for React to process some json, and load views based on the response.

For example:

1- React has a form, response goes out to external API

2- API processes the input, returns a success code unless there was validation issues, and send a response back to the React app

3- React gets the json response, loads a "Success" view, or reloads the form and outputs the erros

Is there a simple way for React to handle this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, you will have to think about how the *state* changes upon the three cases *filling the form*, *sending form/waiting for response*, *view result*. Then the view reacts to the state that the app is in. Think data structure / state first, then I would read up on forms in the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Additionally, the view "reacting" to state could be as simple as an `if` statement that renders different components based on said state. Remember that `render`  gets called every time you call `setState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple...

Basically, you need to track when you initiate request (sending data) and when request is completed (receiving response).

Based on data returned, you decide what to render...
Take a look at this example (working fiddle)

```js
// In this example, we are using JSONPlaceholer service do real
// request and receive response;
const root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const Success = () => (<div>Success!</div>);

const Error = () => (<div>Error! Fix your data!</div>);

const Form = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      processing: false,
      result: undefined,
    };
  },

  submit(event) {
    this.setState({ processing: true });
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(`${root}/posts`, {
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        // your data here...
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        // We simulate succesful/failed response here.
        // In real world you would do something like this..
        // const result = response.ok ? 'success' : 'error';

        const processing = false;
        const result = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'success' : 'error';
        this.setState({ result, processing });
      });
  },

  render() {
    const { result, processing } = this.state;

    if (result === 'success')
        return <Success />;

    return (
      <form>
        Form content here<br/>
        <button onClick={this.submit}>
          { processing ? 'Sending data...' : 'Submit' }
        </button>
        { result === 'error' && <Error /> }
      </form>
    );
  },
});

render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to trigger the new state with setState() from the API callback function such as in the example below, although I recommend using a library such as Redux for state management.

```
var MainComp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {someProp: ""}
    },

    callAPI: function() {
        var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

        $.ajax({
          url: root + '/posts/1',
          method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(data) {
          this.setState({someProp: data.body})
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function(){
      return (        
        <div>                 
          <h2>{this.state.someProp}</h2>
          <button onClick={this.callAPI}>Async</button> 
        </div>
      )      
    }
});



React.render(<MainComp/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Please note this is a naive example, you should still cover up error cases and build a logic to trigger different views based on state.